# How do I diagnose the DNS settings for a "missing blog"?

Tags: domain-name-system

I used to have a blog under the domain "thehashtable.com", so I have a domain account under that name on my hosting service. When that domain name expired on GoDaddy, I created a domain alias on the hosting service called "thepraxis.co.za", still under my "thehashtable.com" account.  This worked, i.e. typing "thepraxis.co.za" into a browser address bar would cause the browser to load my WordPress blog's home page.

Last week I was fiddling around with DNS records for "thepraxis.co.za" and "thehashtable.com", and I don't recall what I did, but now typing "thepraxis.co.za" into the browser gives a "Google Chrome could not find thepraxis.co.za" error. I can ping the URL though, and the blog installation is still active on the host.

How can I use elementary tools like nslookup to determine why my blog is missing and qwhat DNS records I need to restore to get it 'live' again?

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hostname must match the IP. Issue `nslookup thepraxis.co.za` better `dig thepraxis.co.za` and look if you get the expected IP. If not change it in the DNS (hint it's the A record).

Repeat with any other hostname.

And as a hint: I can access the site and see a "blog" with just one post.

Another hint: theashtable.com has expired. Re-register or it will get lost.

Answer (score 0):

The domain `thepraxis.co.za` resolves to `64.244.63.109` and I can load your blog. The domain `thehashtable.com` resolves to `208.87.32.75` and loads a GoDaddy.com for sale page.

```
dig  thepraxis.co.za +short
64.244.63.109

dig thehashtable.com +short
208.87.32.75
```